# Django issue with admin and static folder into runserver response

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have this project with these folders and I want to fix the output of *runsever* command versus static folder and admin area:

```
(env) [mythcat@desk mysite]$ tree -d
.
├── mysite
│   ├── __pycache__
│   └── static
│       ├── admin
│       │   ├── css
│       │   │   └── vendor
│       │   │       └── select2
│       │   ├── fonts
│       │   ├── img
│       │   │   └── gis
│       │   └── js
│       │       ├── admin
│       │       └── vendor
│       │           ├── jquery
│       │           ├── select2
│       │           │   └── i18n
│       │           └── xregexp
│       └── rest_framework
│           ├── css
│           ├── docs
│           │   ├── css
│           │   ├── img
│           │   └── js
│           ├── fonts
│           ├── img
│           └── js
└── test001
    ├── migrations
    ├── static
    └── templates
        └── test001
```

I add into urls.py :

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
...
urlpatterns = [
...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

The settings.py is set with applications and this source code:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
...
TEMPLATE_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),]
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    '/home/mythcat/projects/django/mysite/mysite/static/',
    '/home/mythcat/projects/django/mysite/mysite/static/admin/',
    '/home/mythcat/projects/django_chart/mysite/mysite/static/admin/css',
    '/home/mythcat/projects/django/mysite/mysite/static/rest_framework/',]
```

I used this:

```
(env) [mythcat@desk mysite]$ python3 manage.py collectstatic
...
177 static files copied to '/home/mythcat/projects/django_chart/mysite/mysite/static', 165 unmodified.
```

But I got this errors:

```
[26/Jan/2020 19:46:57] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 7742
[26/Jan/2020 19:46:57] "GET /static/admin/css/base.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[26/Jan/2020 19:46:57] "GET /static/admin/css/responsive.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[26/Jan/2020 19:46:58] "GET /static/admin/css/fonts.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[26/Jan/2020 19:47:03] "GET /admin/auth/user/ HTTP/1.1" 200 6612
[26/Jan/2020 19:47:03] "GET /static/admin/css/changelists.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
```

Comment: A 304 is not an error, it is a redirect.

Comment: yes is a redirect with a response .. I want to fix these redirects to static folder and files.